# Ansible win_unzip Module takes far to long

Tags: windows, zip, ansible, unzip

At our customer the Ansible module [win_unzip](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_unzip_module.html) takes for to long when executed. Our code is:

```
  - name: unzip zip package into C:\server\dlls 
    win_unzip:
      src: "{{app_path}}\\app_dll.zip"
      dest: "{{app_path}}\\dlls"
      rm: true
```

This step takes more than 10 minutes. The zip file is copied with [win_copy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/win_copy_module.html) in the direct step before, code is here:

```
  - name: copy zip package to C:\server
    win_copy:
      src: "path2zip.zip"
      dest: "{{app_path}}\\app_dll.zip"
```

The extraction successfully finishes, but it blocks our Pipeline for more than 10 minutes, which isn´t acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We reduced the time needed to unzip the package with the help of the Powershell Module [Expand-Archive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive) to nearly zero. Here is the code:

```
  - name: name: unzip zip package into C:\server\dlls 
    win_shell: "Expand-Archive {{app_path}}\\app_dll.zip -DestinationPath {{app_path}}\\dlls"
```

Our pipeline is now fast again, but it would be nice to have a fast Ansible win_unzip Module!

Comment: Just want to add that this requires Powershell 5 installed on the machine.